# How to Place 3 Images in 1 Cell

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have implemented [LazyTableImage](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/LazyTableImages/Introduction/Intro.html) in my sample Project. I want to show to 3 Images in my 1 cell, can you tell me how can i do that here is my sample code which is give below i can try to do that but its not shown 3 images in 1 cell can i make the algorithm which works fine in other projects but LazyTableImage its not working please tell me how could i do that...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    static NSString *PlaceholderCellIdentifier = @"PlaceholderCell";

    int nodeCount = [self.currentSelectedCategoryArray count]/4;

    if (nodeCount == 0 && indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                           reuseIdentifier:PlaceholderCellIdentifier] autorelease];   
            cell.detailTextLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
            cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        }

        cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"Loading…";

        return cell;
    }

    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.detailCatTable dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    }

    int check = indexPath.row;
    check = check*3;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){

            if(check+i < [self.currentSelectedCategoryArray count]){

                if (nodeCount > 0)
                {
                    // Set up the cell...
                    imageClass *imgC = [self.currentSelectedCategoryArray objectAtIndex:check+i];

                    cell.textLabel.text = imgC.imageName;
                    cell.detailTextLabel.text = imgC.imageID;

                    // Only load cached images; defer new downloads until scrolling ends
                    if (!imgC.cImage)
                    {
                        if (tableView.dragging == NO && tableView.decelerating == NO)
                        {
                            [self startImageDownload:imgC forIndexPath:indexPath];
                        }
                        // if a download is deferred or in progress, return a placeholder image
                        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"imageFrame.png"];                
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.imageView.image = imgC.cImage;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 1 `imageView` in `cell`. you should create custom `UITableViewCell` as suggested @alan duncan.

in your code you can have like this :

```
switch(i){
     case 0:
      ((UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1]).image = imgC.cImage;
     break;

     case 1:
      ((UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:2]).image = imgC.cImage;
     break;

     case 2:
      ((UIImageView*)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:3]).image = imgC.cImage;
     break;
}
```

I hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

I would design a custom `UITableViewCell` in its own nib; so that you can layout your three `UIImageView` instances visually.

Then instead of `[[UITableViewCell alloc] init...]` you will load the cell from the nib, either directly or instantiate via `UINib`.